# Play audio through onclick event on safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, mobile-safari

I just can't get to play an audio on safari, it works on all others browsers. I know that safari doesn't allow autoplay but this is not the case.

```
<td id="audioBtn">
    <audio id="test666">
        <source src="mySound.wav" type="audio/wav" />
    </audio>
    <button style="border:0px solid transparent;" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"
    name="button" onclick="$('#test666')[0].play();">
        <i class="fa fa-file-audio-o fa-2x"></i>
    </button>
</td>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://medium.com/@curtisrobinson/how-to-auto-play-audio-in-safari-with-javascript-21d50b0a2765

Comment: no, I don't need auto-play. Thanks anyways

Comment: Your code works correctly on the mobile and desktop safari (arczi.ct8.pl). What is the link to the project? I will check where the error is